# java constructor: this(.)

Tags: java, constructor

Why the output is "021"? Why there are "0" and "1"(since "i" get "2" why it changes to "1")?

```
public class C {
       protected int i;
       public C(int i){
               this(i,i);
               System.out.print(this.i);
               this.i=i;
}
      public C(int i, int j) {
               System.out.print(this.i);
               this.i=i+j;
}
       public C(){
              this(1);
              System.out.print(i);
}
      public static void main(String[] args) {
             C c=new C();
}}
```

Answer (score 7):

`C()` calls `C(1)` which calls `C(1,1)`

- `C(1,1)` prints **0** (the default value of `this.i`) and assigns 2 (`i+j`) to `this.i`
- then `C(1)` prints **2** and assigns 1 to `this.i`
- then `C()` prints **1**

Answer (score 2):

I think this is better for understanding:

```
public C(int i) {
    this(i, i);
    System.out.println("*"+this.i);
    this.i = i;
}

public C(int i, int j) {
    System.out.println("@"+this.i);
    this.i = i + j;
}

public C() {
    this(1);
    System.out.println("#"+i);
}
```

Now, you can get the sequence of these methods when you invoke C();

Answer (score 1):

Here the code commented, you will understand your problem now,

```
public class C {
    protected int i;

    public C(int i) {
        this(i, i); // got to two parameter constructer and after the result print the next line
        System.out.print(" + second "+this.i); // print value of i which is come from C(int i, int j) = 2
        this.i = i; // set the value of i to 1
    }

    public C(int i, int j) {
        System.out.print("first "+this.i); // print the value of i (in this case 0 the default value)
        this.i = i + j; // set i to 2
    }

    public C() {
        this(1); // got to one parameter constructer and after the result print the next line
        System.out.print(" + Third is "+i); // print value of i which is come from C(int i) = 1
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
    }
}
```

I hope that help.